# How to transform a npm test script to a grunt task?

Tags: javascript, node.js, gruntjs

I have the following script with my nodeJS.

```
"scripts": {
    "test": "babel-tape-runner 'test/**/*.js' | tap-notify | tap-diff "
}
```

If I run my tests with npm test everything runs properly, but I would prefer to have it all in a gruntfile. Is there a way to configure grunt to run the tests?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to transform a npm script to a grunt task?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24791260/how-to-transform-a-npm-script-to-a-grunt-task)

Comment: I would probably use the `grunt-exec` plugin to accomplish this need: https://www.npmjs.com/package/grunt-exec